# Detect different versions of the same .NET assembly

Tags: .net, reflection, version, .net-assembly

My app has a plug-in structure and it is possible the there are two versions of a plugin on the system. If the filenames collide, but the filehashes are different, I'm most likely dealing with two distinct versions of the same assembly. How can I be sure without loading the files in question? I need to be able to delete the files so loading them from the disk is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry about it.  The application manifest tracks assemblies by the combination of name, version and culture.

If you are dynamically loading the assemblies:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load
            ("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
```

Comment: I'm not. I recently changed the way my app finds plugins and my users are already running into all sorts of loading collisions.